# Accessing DependencyProperty: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I would like to load data into my WPF DataGrid when a DependencyProperty value changes. I thought something as simple as this would work but it does not;

```
public SQLiteDb.Attorney attorney
{
    get { return (SQLiteDb.Attorney)GetValue(attorneyProperty); }
    set {
        SetValue(attorneyProperty, value);
        GetAttorneysIdentitiesAsync(); //Load the data here.
    }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty attorneyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("attorney", typeof(SQLiteDb.Attorney),
      typeof(AttorneyDetails), new PropertyMetadata(new SQLiteDb.Attorney()));
```

But I end up getting thread exceptions which I have very little experience about. The method `GetAttorneysIdentitiesAsync` looks like this which I guess is trying to access the property value from another thread.

```
public async void GetAttorneysIdentitiesAsync()
{
    AlternativeIdentities = await SQLiteDb.db.Table<SQLiteDb.AttorneyIdentity>().Where(x => x.AttorneyId == attorney.Id).ThenBy(x => x.Id).Take(30).ToListAsync();
    AlternativeIdentitiesGrid.ItemsSource = AlternativeIdentities;
}
```

I get the exception whenever I try to access the property from within the property class.

```
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

Comment: As a note, you should not call anything else than GetValue and SetValue in the CLR wrapper of a dependency property. The reason is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-loading-and-dependency-properties). Use a PropertyChangedCallback, registered by PropertyMetadata, to call GetAttorneysIdentitiesAsync. You should also avoid `async void`. Change it to `async Task` and await it.

Comment: The problem is `GetAttorneysIdentitiesAsync()` is not static and I know how to bypass that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should access the `attorny` property outside a Task thread:

```
public async Task GetAttorneysIdentitiesAsync()
{
    var id = attorney.Id;

    AlternativeIdentities = await SQLiteDb.db.Table<SQLiteDb.AttorneyIdentity>()
        .Where(x => x.AttorneyId == id)
        .ThenBy(x => x.Id)
        .Take(30)
        .ToListAsync();

    AlternativeIdentitiesGrid.ItemsSource = AlternativeIdentities;
}
```

---

Note also that you should not call anything else than GetValue and SetValue in the CLR wrapper of a dependency property. The reason is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-loading-and-dependency-properties).

You should register a PropertyChangedCallback like this:

```
public SQLiteDb.Attorney attorney
{
    get { return (SQLiteDb.Attorney)GetValue(attorneyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(attorneyProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty attorneyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(attorney), typeof(SQLiteDb.Attorney), typeof(AttorneyDetails),
    new PropertyMetadata(new SQLiteDb.Attorney(), attorneyPropertyChanged));

private static async void attorneyPropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    await ((AttorneyDetails)o).GetAttorneysIdentitiesAsync();
}
```

Comment: Holy cow! That worked! I have wasted a day on this! Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Please see the edit for the PropertyChangedCallback.

Comment: Note also that `new SQLiteDb.Attorney()` may be a bad idea for a default value, as it would be used by all AttorneyDetails instances. Finally, there are widely accepted naming conventions. The property should better be named `Attorney`.